# Why Am I Getting ELIF Invalid Syntax Error?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-3.5

When i went from python 2.7 to python 3.5 I started having problem with ELIF statement.
I am using PyCharm so when i enter elif statement it shows an error and this[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFIi7.png)

[this is what jumps up as error solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFIi7.png)

and when I press it this happens but code still doesn't works...

doesn't let me post this pic, it will be in comments

Anyways, i cant post code for some reason so it will be in comments if you need him and please help me if you can because this is not first time happening, I can't find help anywhere and well it's really annoying...

Comment: you can't have bare `elif` statements they need to be preceded by an `if`. In addition to that, your `if` should use the equality operator `==` and *not* an assignment with `=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to firstly type "if" and the "elif". So it should be something like that:

```
def choice(game):           #CHOOSING GAME
while game > 3 or game < 1:
    print("\nSomething went wrong, enter game you want again (only numbers 1, 2, 3!")
    game = int(input("--> "))
    if game == '1': #bug here
        print("You chose Coin flip game")
        os.system('python coinflip.py')
    elif game == '2': #and here
       print("You chose Horse racing game")
        os.system('python horseracing.py')
    elif game == '3': #and here
        print("You chose Loto game")
        os.system("python loto.py")
```

Comment: ohhh, I see, thank you very much! This helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your first error is not having an initial `if` statement as well as having `game = '1':` instead of `game == '1':`. If you look at my code I have fixed these errors and fixed the indentation as it was causing some bugs

```
import os

print("\nWelcome, enter Your name please")
name = input("--> ")

def username(name):         #NAME
    while len(name) < 2:
        print("There was an error")
        name = input("\nPlease enter Your name again -->")
    else:
        print("Hello,", name)
username(name)

def menu():         #MENU
    print("\nWelcome to the menu")
    print("From here You can chose the game")
    print("For now, we have only 3 game but there will be plenty more!")
    print("Chose game by it's number  ")
    print("1 - Coin flip| 2 - Horse racing| 3 - Loto|")
menu()
game = int(input("--> "))

def choice(game):           #CHOOSING GAME
    while game > 3 or game < 1:
        print("\nSomething went wrong, enter game you want again (only numbers 1, 2, 3!")
        game = int(input("--> "))
    if game == '1': #if statement first and two "=" signs
        print("You chose Coin flip game")
        os.system('python coinflip.py')
    elif game == '2': #use tab to indent properly
        print("You chose Horse racing game")
        os.system('python horseracing.py')
    elif game == '3': #keep indentations the same throughout
        print("You chose Loto game")
        os.system("python loto.py")
choice(game)
```